# How to Create Form Template in Go Programming?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

How to Create Login Form (username and Password) Template in Go Programming?

Comment: Have a look at http://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/#tmp_6 for an introduction to Go templates. Some more good links are http://golangtutorials.blogspot.com.au/2011/06/go-templates.html , http://jan.newmarch.name/golang/template/chapter-template.html and http://shadynasty.biz/blog/2012/07/30/quick-and-clean-in-go/ .

Comment: @ Intermernet : Thank you. With http://shadynasty.biz/blog/2012/07/30/quick-and-clean-in-go/ link I am Trying to Create template. My project Structure is created with the Go-SDK google app engine. google_appengine/myapp/hello/hello.go file is present, then where to create template folder? I created the "template" folder in "hello" folder but getting error "panic: open templates/base.html: The system cannot find the path specified" and server stops running. What can be done?

Comment: That sounds like it's looking for the template in a folder called "templates" (not "template") in the "hello" folder. Try creating that folder and moving the template into there. There's more info on specifying which files to load at http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.ParseFiles . Look at both the `ParseFiles` function and the `ParseGlob` function which will allow you use wildcards such as `templates.ParseGlob("templates\*.html")`.

Comment: @Intermernet : template is renamed as templates and it is placed in myapp/hello/templates but still the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using *template* on appengine is only posible if you pass the html from field, because of appengine rules you dont have access to the filesystem

here is an example

```
const loginTemplateHTML = `<html>
  <body>
    <form action="/login" method="post">
      <div><input name="username" type="text" /></div>
      <div><input name="password" type="password" /></div>
      <div><input type="submit" value="login"></div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
    `    
var loginTemplate = template.Must(template.New("Login").Parse(loginTemplateHTML))

func login (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if err := loginTemplate.Execute(w,nil); err != nil {
         http.Error(w, err.String(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}
```